# How to unit test cell from storyboard

Tags: ios, xcode, unit-testing, swift

I want to check if a cell (storyboard!) fulfills certain requirements (like has certain properties etc.) But I do not seem to be able to instantiate it from the storyboard.

```
override func setUp() {
    tableView = UITableView()
    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: NSBundle(forClass: self.dynamicType))
    viewController = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("tvcStorageList") as? tvcStorageList
    let x = viewController.view
    navController = MockNavigationController(rootViewController: viewController)
    successMockDBDidReplaceProductDB = substituteWithMockDatabase()
    viewController.viewDidLoad()
}


func testCorrectTableCellIsReturned() {
    viewController.viewDidLoad()
    let cell = viewController.tableView(tableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath: NSIndexPath(forRow: 0, inSection: 0))
    println(cell)
}
```

// the table....

```
  override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("StorageCell") as! Storage2TableViewCell

    let row = indexPath.row
    let temp = storageList[row]
    let thisStorage = temp
    cell.name.text = temp.name
```

Trying to test a get a bad access where the cell should be dequeued.

Comment: Did you set the identifier in storyboard? And change the cell class for the prototype in storyboard?

Comment: yes. everything is working as expected running the app. only when running the test it fails

Answer (score 3):

I found the solution myself. Quite stupid mistake actually....

I has to be

```
let cell = viewController.tableView(viewController.tableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath: NSIndexPath(forRow: 0, inSection: 0))
```

Answer (score 1):

As posted [here][1] (Swift 3) I had to call the cellForRow the datasource function cellForRowAt function instead of accessing straight from the tableView.cellForRow function

```
//this 
let cell = controller.tableView(controller.tableView, cellForRowAt: IndexPath(row: 0, section: 0))

//instead of this
let cell = controller.tableView.cellForRow(at: IndexPath(row: 0, section: 0))
```

Answer (score 0):

Since iOS11, this solution can trigger an error if you try to iterate in more than once cell.

`Attempted to dequeue multiple cells for the same index path, which is not allowed. If you really need to dequeue more cells than the table view is requesting, use the -dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier: method (without an index path). Cell identifier: cell, index path:`

I found some insights on a [Github project](https://github.com/kif-framework/KIF/issues/1007#issuecomment-333222874)

> "this is a new assert in iOS 11 that was added to prevent misusing this API on UITableView. The dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath: method should only be called once inside of tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath: in response to a callback from the table view."
>
> Most clients hit this assert because they mistakenly call their own implementation of tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath: from somewhere else, instead of the normal case where the table view calls that method, which results in a cell being dequeued for the passed index path that the table view did not ask for. In most cases, the client is doing this to (incorrectly) try to get the visible cell for that index path from the table view, which is correctly done by asking the table view directly using cellForRowAtIndexPath: on the UITableView.

For my test cases, I used `tableView.visibleCells` to replace that bit for now. Also, programmatically scrolling between elements cal help too in that purpose.